# Enabling multiple cameras in Autoware(with LGSVL)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!,
Is there any documentation/pointers on how to enable multiple cameras on(for example: with LGSVL) Autoware.AI?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357395/enabling-multiple-cameras-in-autoware(with-lgsvl)/) by [SenRamakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/54895/senramakri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what you mean by "enabling" multiple cameras. Autoware.AI uses a decentralized sensor processing architecture so the data from each sensor is processed independently into abstract items like "objects" or" obstacles" before being used.

If you want to use multiple cameras to, for example, detect objects, each camera will have its own object detection pipeline and you'll have to come up with a way to combine the objects detected by all of the cameras before they are used, for example, in the obstacle avoidance node.  The object fusion functionality is not available out-of-the-box but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SenRamakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/54895/senramakri/) on 2020-07-18**:
@josh-whitley - Sorry I was not clear. Yes, the question was to use multiple cameras to have larger field of view around the vehicle. And your answer really helped in terms how to support that use-case, Thanks.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-07-18**:
Please remember to accept the answer if it answered your question (the checkmark under the score buttons).

**Comment by [SenRamakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/54895/senramakri/) on 2020-07-18**:
Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out. (I'm kind of new to this group :-).)